# Combining Multiple PDFs using Pandas dataframe and PyPDF2

Tags: python, pandas, pypdf

I am trying to combine two PDFs by first iterating through a dataframe and then through a file path.

The rename and move function works, however, the program only ever combines the first two pdfs from my list. Below is my code:

```
#set paths
path = 'C:\\Users\\sferrier\\Desktop\\test_1'
dest = 'C:\\Users\\sferrier\\Desktop\\test_1_output'
os.chdir(path)

#creater empty lists to later append to 
slipsheet = []
document = []
new_file = [] 

#load the dataframe
df = pd.read_excel('slip_sheet_exs.xlsx', columns = ['slipsheet', 'filename'])

#iterate through excel and add columns to a list
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    slipsheet.append(row['slipsheet'])
    document.append(row['filename'])

#define merger and i for later use in the for loop 
merger = PdfFileMerger()
i = 0 

#combine the pdfs and move them
for files in os.dir():
    merger.append(slipsheet[i]) 
    merger.append(document[i])
    merger.write(slipsheet[i] + " - " + document[i])
    new_file = path + '\\' + slipsheet[i] + " - " + document[i]
    shutil.move(new_file, dest)
    i= i+1
    if slipsheet == slipsheet[i-1]:
         continue 
    elif i == len(df):
         break
```

Something has to be wrong with the following but I am not sure what:

```
for files in os.dir():
    merger.append(slipsheet[i]) 
    merger.append(document[i])
    merger.write(slipsheet[i] + " - " + document[i])
```

Comment: 1) What type of argument do you pass to `merger.append`? This method expects an input file object or path. 2) You never use the name `files` in your loop.

Comment: I am sending a string to merger.apend. I can use list in document to create a path. I am not sure why not using files is a problem.

Comment: Not necessarily a problem, but you could make the code cleaner and save about four lines using e.g. `for i, __ in enumerate(os.dir())`. Btw what _is_ `os.dir`?